# localization method

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using [hector_slam package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/MappingUsingLoggedData) and i want to make localization but using kinect
I was about to use `Amcl`, but I know it depends on the [Calibrate Odometry and Gyro](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrate%20Odometry%20and%20Gyro)..Unfortunately I do not have [Power and Sensor Board](http://store.iheartengineering.com/ihe-0200-0000-fa00.html)  in my irobot create

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54046/localization-method/) by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-02**:
What is your question?

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-02**:
i want suggestion to localization method which works with laser of kinect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you dont have odomtery reading .. try looking into VSLAM or RGBD slam. They might not require odometry readings. It is based in vision. I havent used any of it but it might work so look into it.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1